# How can I inspect traffic on my iPhone with Proxyman?

Tags: ios, proxy, traffic, charles-proxy

I'm trying to inspect traffic from specific apps on my iPhone, but it doesn't work.

I followed the steps (turned on proxy, done certificates, and yes, checked VPNs; it's turned off), the IP address of my iPhone appeared in Proxyman tab, but there're only service requests here, like *googleapi.com*, *inappcheck.itunes.apple.com*, and weather.
From the needed apps on my device I only see requests for googleads and stuff.

What did I overlook?

Comment: You can follow the tutorial from RayWenderlich to know how to use Proxyman to inspect traffic from your iOS devices: https://www.raywenderlich.com/25354003-using-proxyman-to-inspect-network-traffic